# How can i get informations from a calling service?

Tags: android

Sorry for not being so specific, but i'm a begginer in Android, and i would like to know if there's a way to get informations from a service call. For example, when you call to *547#412312*233# makes something, and the phones shows you something. Is it possible to manage it inside an app?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean calling an external service and manage it? Usually, in such cases, you use an Intent and the system will handle it according to what apps has it to handle the intent.

You can find more infos about that here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Regarding your example, you can try it on your own with:

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:5551234");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
```